# AWS Amplify Deployment on ReactJS - Module Not Found AWS Exports

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Currently have my login page working in my local environment that I am coding in ReactJS.

My code is:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import NavBar from "../components/navbar";

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

import awsmobile from '../aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

const Login = () =>{

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <NavBar />
      <Authenticator>
        {({ signOut, user }) => (
          <main>
            <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
            <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
          </main>
        )}
      </Authenticator>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

The page locally doesn't present any errors int he code but when I publish my changes to GitHJub and Amplify picks up the new copy of the repo it errors out.

The error from the log in Amplify is:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../aws-exports' in '/codebuild/output/src319668361/src/MyProject/src/pages'

I have seen that the issue could lie with importing the aws-exports file as it should be set as a path in an evironment variable. Is there a way to disable that for now as I am just playing around and learning the library for the first or does my issue lie in something else?

Also, I saw a similar post and tried the `change aws-exports to awsmobile' since it is exported from that generated file as "awsmobile" and I still run into the same issue.

Let me know if I can offer anymore information that can help pinpoint to the cause! Thank you in advance.